# Another question on hereditarily lindelöf space

Tags: general-topology

Let $X^2$ be hereditarily lindelöf ($X$ is regualr.). How to show the diagonal of $X$ is a $G_\delta$-subset in $X^2$? Thanks ahead:)

Comment: Does your definition of Lindelöf require that the space be T$_3$?

Comment: Yes. $X$ is regular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some generalities:

Let $X$ be hereditarily Lindelöf and regular. Let $O \subset X$ be open. Then for every point $x \in O$ find (by regularity) some open subset $V_x$ such that $x \in V_x \subset \overline{V_x} \subset O$. Some countable subset of the $V_x$, say $V_x$ with $x \in C$, $C$ countable, also cover $O$, as $O$ is Lindelöf, so we have that

$$O = \cup_{x \in C} V_x \subset \cup_{x \in C} \overline{V_x} \subset O,$$ so
we have that $O$ is the countable union of closed sets (an $F_\sigma$). Dually we have that every closed subset of $X$ is a $G_\delta$ (taking complements and using de Morgan).  Furthermore, $X$ being Lindelöf and regular implies that it is normal, as shown for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2798296). This shows that $X$ is perfectly normal.

So for a regular Lindelöf space it is equivalent to be hereditarily Lindelöf or to be perfectly normal. (If an open subset is an $F_\sigma$ in a Lindelöf space it is $\sigma$-Lindelöf and thus Lindelöf too, and this suffices for being hereditarily Lindelöf.)

Now $X$ is closed (Hausdorffness!) in $X^2$ and so if the latter space is hereditarily Lindelöf, $X$ is a $G_\delta$ in its square.

Comment: Good job! Thanks Henno. So we don't need $X^2$ be hereditarily lindelof, just need $X$ be herditarily? And by your proof, it seems that if $X$ be hereditarily lindelof, then it also has a regular $G_\delta$ diagonal?

Comment: No, you need the square to be hereditarily Lindelöf, as we use the fact that $X$ is closed in the square. If $X^2$ is, so is $X$, but not reversely.